# Bad text-align in css

Tags: html, css

I am working with html and css and try to do a simple thing but can't figure out how since I'm forced to du UX and I'm not a web designer. So my code looks like that :

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="class1">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class=imageClass" src="image.jpg">
                </a>
                <a class="linkClass2" href="#">
                   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitis
                </a>
             </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
[...]
```

and the result looks like that : [image]

But I want a result like that :
[image]

my css :

```
.class1{
     display: inline-block;
}
.imageClass= {
    border-radius:50%;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-left:5px;
}
.linkClass2{
     vertical-align:top;
     display: inline;
}
```

I don't think that's complicated to do but since I'm not a web designer, I can't find the solution

Comment: How can we see the actual problem with out the complete code. Add css to your snippet

Comment: I doubt this is the problem, but your img's class attribute is missing a double quote.

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao I didn't add it because it useless thing like radius for the img or some vertical-align or display I tried. But add it anyway

Comment: thanks for the duplicate, it wa that